# How do I change the state of a QProgressBar?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, qt5

I have a custom dialog that imitates and embellishes [QProgressDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html) with some additional application-specific information and enables pausing/resuming the worker thread running in the background. Ultimately what I'm looking for is the ability to change the appearance of the [QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) to reflect the paused state as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307515/how-to-change-the-progress-bar-color).

[image: pause progress]

Oddly enough [QWinTaskbarProgress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarprogress.html) seems to support this exact functionality as of Qt 5.2, but a plain [QProgressBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) does not, in Qt4 or Qt5. I'm okay with fiddling around in the Qt source code, but I've dug around in the Qt source code and I can't figure out where the actual state of the form control is queried/provided, so I can't figure out what I need to change. Maybe it's not there because this is strictly a Windows thing, but maybe not?

Using CSS to override the StyleSheet [as recommended in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742148/1666676)) results in a very ugly progress bar, completely different in appearance from the stock Windows 7 progress bar.

Normal:

[image: normal appearance]

Stylesheet:

[image: stylesheet appearance]

I don't want to use this option.

Comment: Yup, the reason you can't find the code that draws the task bar progress bars on Windows 7+ is because it's a feature of Windows, not Qt -- it's part of the `ITaskBarList3` interface.

Comment: I did see that. I guess I assumed that something similar was happening on the Windows/vc++ control objects being used deep in the Qt src.

Answer (score 4):

The simple way is setting [QGraphicsColorizeEffect](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html) to the progress bar.

Like this:

```
QProgressBar* progress = new QProgressBar;
progress->setGraphicsEffect(new QGraphicsColorizeEffect);
```

Result on Win7:

[image]

Umm...the result looks like fine, but we can make it better, only change the chunk colour.

Here is the final result:

[image]

Reimplement `QGraphicsEffect::draw` to specific & customize the colourize effect area:

```
class Colorize : public QGraphicsEffect {
public:
    explicit Colorize(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QGraphicsEffect(parent),
        strength(1),
        color(Qt::red),
        effectRect()
    { }
    quint32 strength;
    QColor color;
    QRectF effectRect;

protected:
    void draw(QPainter* painter) {
        QPoint offset;
        const QPixmap pixmap = sourcePixmap(Qt::LogicalCoordinates, &offset);
        draw(painter, offset, pixmap, QRect());
    }

    void draw(QPainter *painter, const QPointF &dest, const QPixmap &src, const QRectF &srcRect) const
    {
        if (src.isNull())
            return;

        QImage srcImage;
        QImage destImage;

        if (srcRect.isNull()) {
            srcImage = src.toImage();
            srcImage = srcImage.convertToFormat(srcImage.hasAlphaChannel() ? QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied : QImage::Format_RGB32);
            destImage = QImage(srcImage.size(), srcImage.format());
        } else {
            QRect rect = srcRect.toAlignedRect().intersected(src.rect());

            srcImage = src.copy(rect).toImage();
            srcImage = srcImage.convertToFormat(srcImage.hasAlphaChannel() ? QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied : QImage::Format_RGB32);
            destImage = QImage(rect.size(), srcImage.format());
        }
        destImage.setDevicePixelRatio(src.devicePixelRatioF());

        // do colorizing
        QPainter destPainter(&destImage);
        grayscale(srcImage, destImage, srcImage.rect());
        destPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Screen);
        destPainter.fillRect(effectRect, color);
        destPainter.end();

        // alpha blending srcImage and destImage
        if(0 < strength && strength < 1){
            QImage buffer = srcImage;
            QPainter bufPainter(&buffer);
            bufPainter.setOpacity(strength);
            bufPainter.drawImage(0, 0, destImage);
            bufPainter.end();
            destImage = buffer;
        }

        if (srcImage.hasAlphaChannel())
            destImage.setAlphaChannel(srcImage.alphaChannel());

        painter->drawImage(dest, destImage);
    }
};
```

Calculate the grove rect of the progress bar:

```
QRectF getGrooveRect() const {
    StyleOptionProgressBar option;
    option.initFrom(this); // this ⇒ progress bar
    return style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ProgressBarGroove, &option, this);
}

...

class StyleOptionProgressBar : public QStyleOptionProgressBar {
public:
    using QStyleOptionProgressBar::QStyleOptionProgressBar;

    void initFrom(const ColorizeProgressBar* w) {
        init(w);
        minimum = w->minimum();
        maximum = w->maximum();
        progress = w->value();
        text = w->text();
        textAlignment = w->alignment();
        textVisible = w->isTextVisible();
        orientation = w->orientation();
        invertedAppearance = w->invertedAppearance();
    }
};
```

Complete source on [Github](https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/tree/master/ColorizeProgressBar).

BTW, Referred [Qt source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/a37dd93defd91b79fb6730d0ff0515a66a0d3972/src/widgets/effects/qpixmapfilter.cpp)

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just apply the GraphicsEffect to the progress bar, hide its text and add a new label (unaffected by the GraphicsEffect) to show the percentage?  
Not that this isn't a nice example for the draw() function.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP I thought about removing text, but GraphicsEffect changes the whole colour of the progress bar(chunk + background).

Comment: True... isn't there some way to only get the filled part of the bar? Might be a private property, though...

Comment: The first option using `QGraphicsColorizeEffect` with `Qt::darkGray` will accomplish the desired end goal for now (i.e., giving the appearance of stopping), unless a simpler option for recoloring it yellow appears. This is the only way to change the color that I could find since the progressbar color is governed by an (uneditable?) animation.

Comment: @Jiu I think you can use the built-in functions to calculate the chunk size using `progressBar->style()->subElementRect(SE_ProgressBarContents, opt, progressBar)`. Only catch is it must be done from a QProgressBar subclass to get access to `initStyleOption()`.

Comment: @Phlucious Thanks! I tried `SE_ProgressBarContents` with `initFrom` but still got the whole size, `initStyleOption() ` didn't used because that for setting the style. BTW, `SE_ProgressBarLabel` can get the correct label pos & size, so I think this shall be the right way to process.

Comment: @Phlucious I updated the answer & Github, Please take a look. Really thanks for helping me improve it.